# Regex for nested grouping

Tags: regex

I try currently to find a useful regex expression for nested grouping.

What my current data looks like:

```
bundle=>test,value=>{amount=>0.00,country=>DE,currency=>EUR},humble=>test,card=>{type=>VISA,digits=>16,security=>645},data=>test
```

The fields vary very much. Means, the nested expression can either have one field or multiple ones.

What I want to achieve:

```
bundle=>test,value.amount=>0.00,value.country=>DE,value.currency=>EUR,humble=>test,card.type=>VISA,card.digits=>16,card.security=>645,data=>test
```

My current expression looks like this:

```
,(.*?)\=>{(((.*?)\=>(.*?))(\,|}))
```

I want everything which is in front of the main value, for example "value" with the expression `,(.*?)\=>` .
Then I try to fetch the values in between of the brackets `{}` with `((.*?)\=>(.*?))` which can either end with a comma (`,`) or a bracket (`}`).

The problem I have is, that I can't make it work for multiple values. For example by adding a `*` quantifier on the last closing bracket, but out of my opinion it should work like that. So what do I do currently wrong?

Another question is, if it is possible to replace the current groups by the first group and the multiple groups within the brackets mentioned in the upper example "What I want to achieve"?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Congratulations, you just learned that regex are incapable of dealing with nested constructs. This is why they are, among other things, unable to parse HTML, or JSON, or the language you are dealing with here. You will very probalby need to look for - or write - a parser. This looks a bit like PHP - is it?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: I currently don't use a specific tool but try on different possibilities. The kind of data is unknown. It is also kinda weird because it is a normal CSV, but the sixth column is in this weird format. I have never seen anything like this before. I was more thinking that it is JSON or YAML. Okay, then I need to write a parser. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be easier if you use regex together with a programming language. For example, I have this perl code which can produce your desired output:

```
 while($input =~ /([\w\.]+?)=>\{([^\{\}]*?)\}/){
  $name = $1; 
  $content = $2; 
  @vals = split(',', $content);
  @newvals = ();
  foreach $v (@vals){
    $v =~ s/(.*?)(=>.+)/$name\.$1$2/;
    push(@newvals, $v);
  }
  $final = join(',', @newvals);

  $input =~ s/([\w\.]+?)=>\{([^\{\}]*?)\}/$final/;
}
print $input;
```

Input:

```
bundle=>test,value=>{amount=>0.00,country=>DE,currency=>EUR},humble=>test,card=>{type=>VISA,digits=>16,security=>645},data=>{test=>{x=>34,y=>44}}
```

Output:

```
bundle=>test,value.amount=>0.00,value.country=>DE,value.currency=>EUR,humble=>test,card.type=>VISA,card.digits=>16,card.security=>645,data.test.x=>34,data.test.y=>44
```

Comment: Hey glennmark, thank you for sending me perl as a solution. I'm not really familiar with perl, but I will try to solve the solution in C++. Thank you for the code!